# Android HTTP request under AsyncTask show black screen

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i've a question. I use AsyncTask to retrieve json data from a remote server. All work fine if my smatphone have internet connection.
If i try to connect my phone to a wifi witout internet connection, when i launch app it show for a few seconds a black screen.

Il leave black screen when try/catch (for http request) into doBackground return java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.xxxxxx.it": No address associated with hostname

I call asynctask from onResume method:

```
HttpOperation MyTask= new HttpOperation(ctx);
MyTask.execute(url);
```

Where are my problems? Best Regards

Comment: do you have the internet permission?

Comment: Could you advise if you have an internet connection via the wifi or are you expecting for it not to resolve? I am assuming you are expecting this to continue loading the async task at the same time as loading the UI, and therefore should not see a blank screen?

Comment: Yes, i've all Internet permission. I want simulate a case where i have'nt internet connection, but the phone is correctly attached to an access point.

Comment: I've my phone connect to an access point that I have voluntarily disconnected from the internet. I want simulate a case that i have wifi connectivity with internet connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your problem is that your not doing anything if there is nothing to display. Have you considered polling the current internet connection status and displaying a message saying "No Current Connection" on the activity you call it from?

EDIT: Code for polling current internet connection:

```
public boolean checkInternet() {
      ConnectivityManager connection = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      NetworkInfo network = connection.getActiveNetworkInfo();
      if (network == null) { //no connection
       return false;
      } else
       return true;
     }
```

Comment: if (network == null) { //no connection
       return false;
      } else
       return true; 

you can change this snippet with return netword != null
     }

Comment: Your right, that makes things a bit shorter, however I always find it makes it easier to read by breaking it up a bit!

Comment: I use this, but it doesn't tell me is there is an internet connection, but only is wifi is connect to an access point.

Comment: Why don't you just deal with the case of no internet connection directly? For example, if no information is taken from the server, or your HTTPGET returns a failure response code - then create an activity for the circumstance, or display "No Internet Connection" in a textView above the current UI